# Python loop functions arguments

Tags: python, function, arguments

I'm new and just started learning Python from codeacademy. In the function below, I can't understand why the print_board function uses the argument board_in but board_in is not referred anywhere at all?

```
board = []

for i in range(5):
  board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_board(board_in):
  for row in board:
    print row

print_board(board)
```

Comment: This is code directly from CodeAcademy?

Comment: Yeah that is a bit confusing. It's probably just a typo. The code probably _was_ suppose to read: `for row in board_in`.

Comment: @ChristianDean kinda a bad stage of someone's coding journey for such a typo to exist, especially with Python being a huge starting language. I wonder if it can be reported.

Comment: It is indeed not used. This is bad code. It instead uses the global name `board`.

Comment: Yeah, that does suck being a beginner @roganjosh. If this came _straight_ from Codecademy, I might see if I can let them know.

Comment: Yes this is from Codecademy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `board_in` paramater is completely unused. You have found bad code, that *perhaps* meant to use that parameter, but someone made an error and forgot to use it.

The function body instead uses the global name `board` (the same name that is also passed in as an argument to the function call). This is why the code happens to work, but it *won't* work as intended when you pass in something completely different:

```
>>> print_board(None)
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
>>> print_board("This argument is ignored, so it doesn't matter what you pass in")
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
>>> board = [['A new value', 'for the board global'], ['means the output', 'changes']]
>>> print_board(2 + 2)
['A new value', 'for the board global']
['means the output', 'changes']
```

It'll continue to print the `board` list when you pass in something completely different, like `print_board(None)`. And it will fail with a `NameError` when you use `del board` before calling the function (and passing in something else):

```
>>> del board  # remove the global altogether
>>> print_board({'foo', 'bar', 'baz'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in print_board
NameError: global name 'board' is not defined
```

I suspect that the *intended* implementation was:

```
def print_board(board_in):
    for row in board_in:
        print row
```

Now `board_in` is actually being used.

Comment: Great thank you and for the fast response. I thought it was redundant too but I'm still a noob so wasn't sure :)